# activate a virtualenv from inside a folder containing venv folder

Tags: python, virtual-environment

I have the following folder structure:

```
Folder
  |- working_folder  # other stuff in here.
  |- venv  # my venv folder
```

Depending on platform (windows or linux) I would enter the venv and activate the appropriate script to activate the virtualenv. But especially when you're inside the "working_folder" there is a lot of typing involved to get to the venv,script and activation of the venv.

Lazy as I am I wonder whether there is a more convenient way. I am thinking of some kind of python script looking for a venv folder and automatically activate that virtual environment.

The looking for a venv folder is the easy part. But I am getting stuck on how to use a python script to activate my *current* shell with that virtual env.

Anyone any suggestions ? BTW. I am looking for both a linux and windows solution.

Comment: You mean that `. ../venv/bin/activate` is too much typing?

Comment: try to do that in windows...

Comment: Okay, I don't have the joy of using windows... But the only way that you are going to be able to activate the environment in your _current_ shell is going to be via sourcing the activate script in the current shell, possibly via an alias or a function set up in .bashrc if you want to reduce typing. An external executable e.g. python script is not going to be able to do this for you - at the most, it could be used to find it and output the path, but you would still need shell commands to capture that output and actually source the activate script.

Comment: @alaniwi exactly!

Comment: That's too bad..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this - https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ (this is not a python script, but it will be more convenient)

For example, to activate virtual env with virtualenvwrapper all you need is to type this command:

```
workon name_of_your_venv
```

Comment: I can see a lot of remarks on windows implementation of this one. Not sure if this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @sanders yes, but you need to configure it just once.

Answer (score 0):

## call python executable from venv folder

Assuming you what to execute a file `main.py` and there is a subfolder `venv` with the virtual environment for the python code to work:

```
./venv/bin/python main.py
```